# Please, fix the gnome* tags mess

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

Ok, according to the help pages:

> Incorrectly tagged questions are hard to find and answer. If you know of **common, alternate spellings or phrasings for this tag**, add them here so we can automatically correct them in the future. For example, suggest “bike” as a synonym for bicycle, or “sock” for socks.

Now, why is gnome-shell and gnome-shell-extensions synonym of gnome? GNOME, last time I check out, is an umbrella project for an array of libraries, programs, etc. under the same goal. The tag excerpt agrees:

> GNOME (GNU Network Object Model Environment) is a collection of GTK-base software that provides the desktop environment GNOME-Shell. This is a very general tag that should only be used for questions referring to GNOME in general, **and not a specific component.**

The problem is... that specific components like, gnome-shell and gnome-shell-extensions are being directed to that tag, and I mean to ask... why? The gnome related tags has the advantages that most of them start with the prefix `gnome-`, so I can follow the entire gnome questions or just the, i.e. gnome-shell-extensions. Can this be reverted back to 3 separated tags, please?

Comment: In all fairness, show some compassion. If my GNOME panel is broken, and I didn't know that GNOME Panel belongs to gnome-session, it's safe to assume I'm going to tag it with plain GNOME as a tag, which is probably the reason the tags were combined.

Comment: @ECarterYoung that's not excuse to prevent experts from *correctly tagging a question*. Tags are not for people to tags their questions, they are to connect experts with the question they want to answer. If OP tags a question wrongly, there are more than enough users to correct it.

Comment: That's my point... A user is going to tag it gnome because it belongs to gnome proper, but a user is not always an expert.

Comment: @ECarterYoung so you are saying that the synonym doesn't make sense?

Comment: @Braiam He is saying the synonym makes sense, because users aren't going to tag gnome-panel problems [tag:gnome-shell] or [tag:gnome-session], they are going to tag them [tag:gnome].

Comment: @Seth and I said that its not excuses to prevent *the expert* from doing it right. There are enough users to fix tags. GNOME != GNOME shell neither GNOME != gnome-shell-extensions. Also, that synonym goes against the very tag excerpt.

Answer (score 1):

Some of this, anyway, makes sense.

I've gone ahead and removed the [gnome](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/gnome) -> [gnome-shell-extension](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/gnome-shell-extension) synonym.

As to [gnome](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/gnome) -> [gnome-shell](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/gnome-shell), you're going to have to convince me it isn't better to fold gnome-shell questions into gnome. Besides, how many questions about gnome "as a framework" or "the project in general" are we going to get?

Comment: Please, just read the excerpt: This is a very general tag that **should only be used for questions referring to GNOME in general**, and not *a specific component*. I want to answer gnome-shell question, as I use Debian, you can't hope to shove me [all the mess of the gnome tag](http://stackexchange.com/filters/138331/my-filter-3). Two wrongs doesn't make a right. If you want people to correctly tag questions, **just teach them**.

Comment: @Braiam The tag is what we make it, obviously the people who handled those synonyms thought we should use [tag:gnome] for generic gnome questions, they just didn't update the wiki. As for "teaching them" I'm not just referring to users tagging wrong. a) we don't want it to be confusing to new users, b) we don't want to fragment all the gnome questions across the site. Broad tags are not bad, as we've tried to tell you many times. I'd be happy to unlink them if you could show me some *good* reasons, and hopefully have some real community backing behind it.

Comment: There are 7 upvotes in my question, what community support you need?! I already have the backing of the people that cares about it. The ones that does care (me for starters) considers such things just ridiculous and upvoted my plea. If you have any reasonable reason that is not "but poor users doesn't know how to tag questions, aww~" please, share it with me. BTW, I haven't hinted that I want to remove the gnome tag, so why you bring your argument about "broad tags"? I just want two tags that means *totally different things* being totally separated tags, that's all.

Comment: @Braiam "users don't know how to tag questions" was not *my* argument, although it is true. My point is having "gnome" "gnome-shell" "gnome this" "gnome that" gets confusing and is hardly helpful to anyone. Some people obviously thought most gnome questions would be better off folded into one tag: [tag:gnome]. You haven't given me a single good reason to undo that, other than "I want it!".

Comment: BTW, it wasn't "users" but a single moderator that took action.

Comment: It doesn't allow me to answer questions! Is that a powerful reason?

Comment: "**GNOME also includes more than just the shell**, as Unity, GNOME Classic, Pantheon and Cinnamon demonstrate. We could have questions come up which are about the **underlying GNOME 3 system itself, and not GNOME Shell** or whatever other shell is running on top of it. As such, I think **we should recognize that the DE and shell are sufficiently different topics that we keep their tags separate, as well.**" [Community was against it.](http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/2569/169736) A moderator came and did it.

Comment: Read also [Uri Herrera comments about the topic](http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/5700/169736) and read [the "Merging Desktop Environment Tags with Ubuntu "Flavor" Tags" section for more](http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/3512/169736). If we follow what you are saying, we should be merging unity-related tags with unity because, hey, I can't have the component without unity anyways. That just doesn't work. Each component of everything if it's too big should have their own tag.

Comment: Also if you really want to see disaster: [check out gnome questions with the unity tag also](http://askubuntu.com/q/74037/169736). That's really confusing.