# Please undo tag synonymizing: gnome-shell -> gnome

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-synonyms

GNOME Shell is, ultimately, just one component in the GNOME DE. I can use it without many of the other trappings of GNOME, like GDM or Nautilus. It seems very weird that [gnome-panel](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/gnome-panel) - a thing of distant past - is an independent tag, yet, [gnome-shell](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/gnome-shell) is a synonym to [gnome](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/gnome). By whatever logic that makes [gnome-shell](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/gnome-shell) a synonym of [gnome](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/gnome), one could synonymize practically every GNOME app tag to [gnome](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/gnome). [gnome](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/gnome), both by its wiki and what GNOME is, should really be for questions about the desktop environment or the GNOME project as a whole.

Failing that, rename [gnome](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/gnome) to [gnome-shell](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/gnome-shell) - if it is really for GNOME Shell the shell, then that should be reflected in the name. As it stands, [gnome](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/gnome) gets involved in every question that mentions GNOME, especially if it is Ubuntu GNOME, in which case both [gnome](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/gnome) and [ubuntu-gnome](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/ubuntu-gnome) get involved. This is quite senseless.

Comment: Yes. What he said. Gnome-shell is also part of other DEs, it's not restricted to Gnome.

Comment: Good luck there, [Please, fix the gnome\* tags mess](http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/10324)

Comment: @Braiam saw that while writing this one. Figured it's time for a new question.

Comment: I think most people here who say "gnome" mean "gnome-shell", the entire DE. IMO they use "unity" to refer to unity. I agree, "gnome" is a general term and parts of gnome or gnome apps can be installed independent of both unity and gnome-shell, in that case people usually use the name of the application. I have not seen gnome-shell, as a WM, used stand alone or on any other DE such as KDE or XFCE, but I suppose it is possible. For the general usage on this site.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen both MATE and cinnamon use gnome-shell AFAIK. The point here is that the general tag should be `gnome` and _not_ `gnome-shell`. The "whole DE", as you put it, is `gnome`, and `gnome-shell` is only a small part of it.  This synonym is like having `car` as a synonym of `gear shaft`.  If I know my question is about the gear shaft, why do I have to instead tag it with `car`?

Comment: @terdon Cinnamon's ... thing ... can be considered a fork of GNOME Shell. MATE still has the panel+window manager separation (mate-panel + marco). In any case, I agree with you in the DE != panel+window-manager point.

Comment: When people use mate or cinnamon they use the mate and cinnamon tags. While your analogy to a car works for cars perhaps, it does not work for language. The vast majority of people who use "gnome" are referring to gnome-shell, just a fluke of how most people the language / term "gnome". So while your semantics are correct, it is more an issue of how the language is used. You can also argue about what "linux" means. Just the kernel ? Kernel + gnu ? Kernel + gnu + X ? General term for "distributions" ? The use of the language is not as precise as you envision.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen "The vast majority of people who use "gnome" are referring to gnome-shell". No, they are not. Many questions tagged `gnome` have something to do with GNOME (usually some GNOME app), but often nothing or little to do with GNOME Shell.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen please, provide examples of people doing so, I've semn by far many more people referring to "gnome" as the whole environment and not the shell (granted, that was before the whole synonym stuff took place, against community best wishes)

Comment: There is a lot of noise, but if you search for the "gnome tag" these two come up - http://askubuntu.com/questions/621493/gnome-shell-3-16-3-19-update and http://askubuntu.com/questions/621456/problem-with-running-full-screen-apps-in-gnome-shell-with-wine . Both using the gnome tag (no other tags) and asking about gnome-shell. A lot of questions is it unclear what they are asking about as they are using "gnome" as a non-specific term. That is about the extent of my interest in reviewing the gnome tags. It was rather trivial to find examples of people using "gnome" when them mean "gnome-shell"

Comment: @bodhi.zazen remember that gnome-shell is synonymized to gnome, so, recent questions trying to use gnome-shell tag would have gnome applied. There has been [157 renames in total, last one 2 days ago](http://askubuntu.com/tags/synonyms?filter=all&tab=newest), which seems to fit in the [newest](http://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/gnome?sort=newest) proper [gnome-shell question](http://askubuntu.com/q/621743/). All other newest questions are about gnome in general or some gnome app.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen that's pretty much our point. We're saying that `gnome-shell` is useful for questions that are specifically about the shell and not the DE. People don't use `gnome-shell` as a synonym of gnome! They either know what it is and use it correctly, or as is more common, have no idea what it is and just use `gnome`. In any case, questions about the gnome shell should probably be tagged with _both_ `gnome` _and_ `gnome-shell`, but I see no benefit in having these two combined.

Comment: I am not the one you have to convince. "gnome" should refer to what the Gnome project ships by default, and that is gnome shell. Thus by definition, gnome == gnome-shell + libs + additional applications (NM, Nautilus, etc). Other DE or, IMO, have other tags, such as unity or mate or what not. If they are not referring to the DE no need for the gnome tag, use an application tag. Just because one makes use of gnome libs or apps != gnome. Also the gnome project will not maintain non-gnome apps or libs, such as mate. So IMO it is you who is confusing the definition of gnome.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen no. Gnome != gnome-shell. That's like saying that Gnome == gnome-terminal. The gnome-shell is a big part of the gnome DE but it has issues that are specific to it and we should be able to tag accordingly. Not all questions about gnome-shell are also about the gnome DE and the vast majority of questions about gnome are not about the shell at all. Most users don't even know the shell exists so why are these synonyms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The synonym has now been removed. The next time someone tries to add [gnome-shell](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/gnome-shell) it will be created as a new tag.

Comment: Tag and info created, thanks!