# I created a new tag "csm" and someone changed it to "bios"

Tags: discussion, tags

I created a new tag, [csm](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/csm), but it was replaced with [bios](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/bios) on [one of my questions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/870452). I'd like to challenge this, and propose the creation of the [csm](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/csm) tag for things related to CSM under the UEFI spec.

While [csm](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/csm) is also covered by [bios](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/bios), so are many other BIOS-related technologies, which all have their own respective tags. It has enough weight to stand on its own, similar to how [usb](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/usb) can stand its weight against [computer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/computer), even though the latter can very easily cover the former.

Comment: I think CSM is valid, but maybe keep BIOS in there?

Comment: Do you mean the new tag should be `csm-bios`, or do you mean if ever you use the new tag `csm` you should always include the additional tag `bios` at the same time?

Comment: I mean use both.

Comment: Sounds good. Actually I'm using four: bios, csm, uefi and boot. :D

Answer (score 6):

If you do add a tag, at least add an excerpt. I saw no information about the tag, saw the question said it was legacy BIOS support in UEFI and so changed it BIOS.

As for changing all tags to computer, we have some pretty ridiculous tag synonmizing: [Please undo tag synonymizing: gnome-shell -> gnome](http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/13977/158442), so don't rule it out.

Comment: Do you mean add an excerpt within the question stating a new tag is being created and why it is justified?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix no, add an excerpt to the tag wiki, not the question. If you go to the tag page, you'll see it says that "The csm tag has no usage guidance, can you help us create it?" Without that, the tag can be ambiguous.

Comment: I had asked about tag wiki edits when I hit 5K in AU General chatroom a month ago or so and never got an answer on what it really means. I think you are alluding to that now but frankly I don't understand. The software simply asks "are you sure you want to create a new tag?" There is no panel popping up asking for expansion on what the tag means and/or why it is relevant / needed.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix yes, the tag creation process doesn't involve the wiki. You have to go to the tag page (http://askubuntu.com/tags/csm) and then click on the "can you help us create it" link. Under 20k or so, your edits need to be approved by two others. The tag excerpt is shown when you hover over a tag name (for example, the UEFI tag excerpt mentions CSM)

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix for example, see two tags I created recently: http://askubuntu.com/tags/systemd-journald/info and http://askubuntu.com/tags/atd/info

Comment: Never thought about there being a journal daemon even though I've used journalctl.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Maybe that was my bad - I thought I'd answered your question in chat about the 5k privilege but I obviously should have given it more attention. Whenever I remember to, I check the new tags page and untag stuff (to kill the tags) if the new tag seems like a bad idea so I'm guilty in theory on that count as well. I agree with muru - please write an excerpt at least, otherwise when I check the new tags I'll see one question and no explanation of what the tag is for, and probably untag. (5k privilege = review *suggested edits* to tag wikis. Editing tag wikis directly = 20k priv)